# Proper way to rise an event from one class and handle it in other class

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, async-await, eventhandler

I am building api for one application. what i want is when I get a new order, i have to insert it in DB and I want to rise an event (without blocking my api call may be async). so that latter in other class i can handle that event and do the other work like send the new order notification to account and send order update to user using pubnub.

```
     public class OrderService : IOrderService
            {
                public delegate void OrderEventHandler(Order order,bool isNewOrder);

                public static event OrderEventHandler OrderEvents = delegate { };

                public OrderService()
                {
                    OrderEventListener listener = new OrderEventListener();
                    OrderEvents += new OrderEventHandler(listener.HandleOrderEvents);
                }

                #region Methods

                public void Test()
                {
                    INPRODataFacade facade = new NPRODataFacade();
                    var unitOfWork = facade.GetUnitOfWork();
                    var order = unitOfWork.OrderRepository.Find(o => o.OrderID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
                    unitOfWork.Commit();
                    facade.ReturnUnitOfWork();

                    RiseEvent(order,true);
                }

       private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RiseEvent(Order order,bool isNewOrder)
            {
                if (order == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                OrderEvents(order,isNewOrder);
            }
        }


 public class OrderEventListener
    {
        PubNub.PubNub pubNub = null;
        const string ChanelPrifix = "fasttract";

        public OrderEventListener()
        {
            pubNub = new PubNub.PubNub(ConfigurationSettings.PubNub_SubscribeKey, ConfigurationSettings.PubNub_PublishKey, ConfigurationSettings.PubNub_SecretKey, ConfigurationSettings.PubNub_SSlOn);
        }

        public void HandleOrderEvents(Order order, bool isNewOrder)
        {
            string chanelName = isNewOrder ? string.Format("{0}_{1}", ChanelPrifix, order.AccountID)
                                : string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", ChanelPrifix, order.AccountID, order.OrderID);


            var channel = pubNub.Channel(chanelName);
            channel.Publish(new PubNubMessageModel { Message = GetMessage( order, isNewOrder) });

        }

        public string GetMessage(Order order,bool isNewOrder)
        {
            string message = string.Empty;
            if(isNewOrder)
            {
                message = "You have recieved a new order #" + order.OrderID;
                return message;
            }

            message = order.Status.ToString();

            return message;
        }


    }
```

Here have noticed that it is blocking my api call. means I am not getting api response back until event handler finished its execution. is this the right way to handle events ? I think there should be a way that i just add events while getting new order and then in listener i process that events anytime without blocking api call.

Comment: It really depends on context.  If by design the event listeners cannot impact the original event being notified (i.e. no value is returned via the event arguments and an exception is not expected to be thrown to impact handling) and there is no inherrent time or sequence sensitivity requirement then asynchronous is probably the way to go, especially if there may be GUI event listeners that may impose their own threading restrictions.  If you want to go asynchronous just replace OrderEvents(... with OrderEvents.BeginInvoke(...

Comment: OrderEvents.BeginInvoke is not rising the event in event handler and event is never getting fire after api call return !

Comment: @ Ben Jackson: i am not expecting any return value or any exception log. Processing of event is totally a background job !

Comment: Strange - should definitely work - is the process definitely staying open after the call to Test, and can you confirm how you are calling BeginInvoke?

Comment: i tried OrderEvents.BeginInvoke(order,isNewOrder,null,null) as it is expecting callback and some object i passed null.